# Maximum lines of code permitted in a Java class?

Tags: java

How many lines of code can a `.java` file contain? Does it depend on the JVM being used?

Answer (score 35):

To extend upon [Jonas's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107855/is-there-any-no-of-lines-code-limit-for-a-java-class#107870), the Java Virtual Machine Specification, [Section 4.8 Constraints on Java Virtual Machine Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#40222) says that:

> The Java virtual machine code for a
>   method, instance initialization method
>   (§3.9), or class or interface
>   initialization method (§3.9) is stored
>   in the code array of the Code
>   attribute of a method_info structure
>   of a class file. This section
>   describes the constraints associated
>   with the contents of the
>   Code_attribute structure.

Continuing to Section 4.8.1, Static Constraints

> The static constraints on a class file
>   are those defining the well-formedness
>   of the file. With the exception of the
>   static constraints on the Java virtual
>   machine code of the class file, these
>   constraints have been given in the
>   previous section. The static
>   constraints on the Java virtual
>   machine code in a class file specify
>   how Java virtual machine instructions
>   must be laid out in the code array and
>   what the operands of individual
>   instructions must be.
>
> The static constraints on the
>   instructions in the code array are as
>   follows:
>
> ...
>
> - The value of the code_length item must be less than 65536.
>
> ...

So a method does have a limit of 65535 bytes of bytecode per method. (see note below)

For more limitations to the JVM, see [Section 4.10 Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659).

Note: Although there is apparently a problem with the design of the JVM, where if the instruction at byte 65535 is an instruction that is 1 byte long, it is not protected by exception handler - this is listed in footnote 4 of Section 4.10.

Answer (score 9):

I believe there is a 64kb limit on bytecode size per method.

Comment: There is a bug/rfe logged with Sun for this at http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4262078

Comment: The bug no longer exists.  Or at least, it is no longer publicly visible.  RFEs related to similar limits have been closed as "will not fix".

Answer (score 8):

There is no limit on "lines of code", but there is a limit on total size.  Each method has a 64kb limit.

I've only ever run into this with code generation tools.

If you are coming close to the limit, be careful.  A lot of profiling and monitoring tools use byte code insertion.  They can push you over the top if you're too close.  What's worse is that they often alter your class files after compilation.  Everything compiles and runs in your development environment, but it crashes when you turn on your monitoring tools in Test or QA.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned the above, there is no limit on "lines of code” per class in java, we can probably use 200 lines as a good guideline and not exceed 500 lines per class.

Comment: May I know how to handle it in android, because basic level like UIview casting and JSON Parsing alone it crosses 500 line. any tips and trick you have please share.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if we have say 20 methods in a business level class each containing 30 lines?

Comment: @MohanRajS JSON parsing should go to separate class, activity should only contain essential methods and variables that directly link to UI. Please refer to M-V-V-M architecture for more details https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 5):

I remember actually running into this limit once in a complex JSP page in Tomcat 4 (way in the past when people were still using JSPs). The java file generated from the JSP had a method that was too big to compile, I think I had to split up the file or do some other stunt, which of course was a good idea in terms of readability anyway.

Sun's bug tracker tells me some people [still have the same problem](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4262078).

Comment: been there. worked on a JSP that included a whole bunch of JSPs in a loop, or something along those lines.