# What are the advantages/limitations of using a post fix operator over assignment operator?

Tags: java, assignment-operator

I would like to know in what way a post fix operator is better than an assignment operator. In other words what are the advantages/limitations of using one over the other.

```
int a = 10;
a++;

//over 

int a = 10;
a += 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: can the down voter help me correct the question ? I would like to know why one is more preferred than the other. Is my question a duplicate or is it something that shouldn't have been asked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `a++` and `a--` are easier to write than `a += 1` and `a -= 1`.

Also, let's say you want to execute a method and increment `a` by one.
Your method head: `public static void doSomething(int smth)`

Then there are several things you can do: (let's pretend those lines are part of your main method, also `int a = 10;`

You can use a postfix operator:

```
doSomething(a++);
//this will at first execute your method with a and then increment it by one
```

Or you can use the longer version

```
doSomething(a);
a += 1; //possible too, but longer
```

Also there is `--a` and `++a` which will at first increment a and then hand it over to a method or do something else with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real technical limitations of postfix `++` apart from the obvious one: it can *only* increment by one ... not any other number.  Certainly, it makes ZERO difference to performance.

The other possible difference between the two forms is readability.  In this case, it is a matter of opinion ... and my opinion is that they are equally readable.

However, if you start embedding postfix and prefix increment / decrement in more complicated expressions, that can significantly damage your code's readability; e.g. try figuring out what `a = a++;` does ...

Comment: a = a++ is something which I would never do. There is no point assigning a = a++ when the increment operator itself does the assignment. Possible answer I would go with increment operator over assignment operator is to reduce my code as pointed by @adrian

Comment: @nam - why is "reducing" your code a goal?  The goal *should* be readability ... by yourself AND other people.

Comment: @stephan - Design is actually the reason ! I am trying to follow a coding standard. By the way, I am referring to your answers for this :) [As mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256068/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-lines-of-code-you-can-put-in-an-eclipse-java-d?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There is no difference in compiled code size between ++ and += ... if that is what you are talking about.  And, frankly, if one of your classes is big enough that this kind of thing made a difference, then it is waaaaay too large.