# code too large for try statement and code too large for main error Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“code too large” compilation error in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java)

I have a java code of 5147 lines. However, I can't able to run it because, it is giving error,

```
code too large for try statement
```

and

```
code too large for main
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I've never seen that error before. Can you tell us more about your code?

Comment: Distribute your program beyond more than one class.

Comment: That's a **huge** amount of lines clumped together. Would suggest breaking out the code into separate classes.

Comment: @cheeken, is there any other way ?

Comment: sounds like a serious refactoring project. You'll probably need to break that up into at least few chunks. And congratulations on that error :-)

Comment: @Reimeus, That I want to avoid. Any other way ?

Comment: I think a single method can't be more than 64KB of bytecode. But if you really have reached that limit, you should rethink your design. Big time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107855/is-there-any-no-of-lines-code-limit-for-a-java-class

Comment: How did it got written in the first place, turning dynamic compilation off? :o

Comment: Maybe if you post the entire method here we could give you a better advice! just kidding!

Comment: Why are you not desiring to refactor this code? Why put unreasonable limits on how you should improve your code?

Comment: @Arpssss - No you cannot avoid this.  No there is no other way.