# Mapping over than 5908 data lines using HashMap issue

Tags: java

I would like to match the data and replace with new value but if I put more than 5908 lines of data in HashMap. It's given error. How to solved this issue or another solution?

```
String str = "aaa bob ccc ddd .....";
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("aaa","eee"); // data that I would like to match and replace it
map.put("ddd","fff");
.     
.     
.   // more than 5908 lines  
. 
.    
map.put("zzz"."yyy");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z_]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str) // matching process

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) { // if found and replace
   String replace = map.get(matcher.group());
   if (replace == null) { // if not just print it back
      replace = matcher.group();
   }
   matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + "");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no signficance to the 5908 with respect to the hash map. There is simply a [64kB limit on the bytecode size of any one method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107855/maximum-lines-of-code-permitted-in-a-java-class).

You could put the calls to `map.put` in multiple methods, e.g. 5000 calls per method; that's not especially clean, and not very easy to maintain.

You should consider putting the strings and corresponding replacements into external storage, e.g. a file or a database, that you load into the hash map at runtime.